# DatasetType is not defined

Tags: fast-ai

I am trying to classify a medical images using straitified cross folding. The following line gives me hardtime :

preds_test, y_test = learn.get_preds(DatasetType.Valid)

as it give "Errortype: "DatasetType" is not defined"

could someone help me to solve this matter ?

I am expecting to safe the result and get the usual metrics